# Get invoice creation date in Invoice PDF

Tags: php, magento, pdf, invoice

I am using this code to get invoice date of order in PDF, and putting this code in this file **"app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php"** 
But it is showing current date instead of invoice creation date.

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($invoiceIncrementId);
$createdDate = strtotime( $invoice->getCreatedAt() );
$page->drawText(
    Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice Creation Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
        $createdDate, 'medium', false
    ),
    35,
    ($top -= 15),
    'UTF-8'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use `strtotime()`,magento itself handles it. Try using this

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($invoiceIncrementId);
$createdDate = $invoice->getCreatedAt();
$page->drawText(
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice Creation Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
            $createdDate, 'medium', false
        ),
        35,
        ($top -= 15),
        'UTF-8'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but it is still giving current date. Check snapshot : http://prntscr.com/bftf2d

Comment: try to echo output of this `Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
            $createdDate, 'medium', false
        )` and see what output it shows

Comment: It is giving this value "Jun 13, 2016" current date.

Comment: then your `$createdDate` must be empty

Comment: Yes that's why need your help to sort out the correct code.

Comment: what you are passing to `$invoiceIncrementId`? Is it id(eg, 42) or Invoice_id(eg, 100000040 )

Comment: from where to get $invoiceIncrementId parameter?

Comment: Pranav, look at the final answer: $order->getRealOrderId();

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with this code.

```
$order_increment_idd = $order->getRealOrderId();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$query      = "Select * from `sales_flat_invoice_grid` WHERE `order_increment_id` ='$order_increment_idd' LIMIT 1";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($query);

foreach ($rows as $values) {
    $createdDate = $values['created_at'];


    $page->drawText(
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
            $createdDate, 'medium', false
        ),
        35,
        ($top -= 15),
        'UTF-8'
    );
}
```